# Create a new column based on count of other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas that looks like

```
col_1   col_2
6       A       
2       A       
5       B       
3       C       
5       C       
3       B       
6       A       
6       A       
2       B       
2       C       
5       A       
5       B
```

and i want to add a new column `col_new` that counts the number of rows with the same elements in `col_1` and `col_2` but excluding that row itself. So the desired output would look like

```
col_1   col_2   col_new
6       A       2
2       A       0
5       B       1
3       C       0  
5       C       0
3       B       0
6       A       2
6       A       2
2       B       0
2       C       0
5       A       0
5       B       1
```

Here what's I tried but I am not sure if it's the right approach:

`df['col_new'] = df.groupby(['col_1', 'col_2']).count()`

But then I got the error: `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['col_new'] = df.groupby(['col_1', 'col_2'])['col_2'].transform('count').sub(1)
```

Output:

```
    col_1 col_2  col_new
0       6     A        2
1       2     A        0
2       5     B        1
3       3     C        0
4       5     C        0
5       3     B        0
6       6     A        2
7       6     A        2
8       2     B        0
9       2     C        0
10      5     A        0
11      5     B        1
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `value_counts` method.

- Create a 3rd column called `col3` and store a tuple of the row values.  Tuples, unlike lists are hashable and can be used to create keys for counting.

  ```
  df["col3"] = df.apply(lambda x: (x[0], x[1]), axis = 1)
  ```

  ```
         col_1 col_2    col3                                                                                              
    0       6     A    (6, A)                                                                                              
    1       2     A    (2, A)                                                                                              
    2       5     B    (5, B)                                                                                             
    3       3     C    (3, C)                                                                                              
    4       5     C    (5, C)                                                                                              
    5       3     B    (3, B)                                                                                              
    6       6     A    (6, A)                                                                                              
    7       6     A    (6, A)                                                                                              
    8       2     B    (2, B)                                                                                              
    9       2     C    (2, C)                                                                                              
    10      5     A    (5, A)                                                                                              
    11      5     B    (5, B)
  ```
- Create a `Series` for value counts. This will be used like a lookup table.

  ```
  value_counts = df["col3"].value_counts()
  ```

  ```
  (6, A)    3
  (5, B)    2
  (2, A)    1
  (3, C)    1
  (5, C)    1
  (3, B)    1
  (2, B)    1
  (2, C)    1
  (5, A)    1
  Name: col3, dtype: int64
  ```
- Map each row to a fourth column called `counts`

  ```
  df["counts"] = df["col3"].map(value_counts)
  ```

  ```
         col_1 col_2    col3  counts
    0       6     A  (6, A)       3
    1       2     A  (2, A)       1
    2       5     B  (5, B)       2
    3       3     C  (3, C)       1
    4       5     C  (5, C)       1
    5       3     B  (3, B)       1
    6       6     A  (6, A)       3
    7       6     A  (6, A)       3
    8       2     B  (2, B)       1
    9       2     C  (2, C)       1
    10      5     A  (5, A)       1
    11      5     B  (5, B)       2
  ```