# Create a new column in Pandas based on count of other columns and a fixed specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is a continuation of my another related question: [Create a new column based on count of other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75439107/create-a-new-column-based-on-count-of-other-columns)

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
col_1   col_2   col_3
6       A       1
2       A       1 
5       B       1
3       C       1
5       C       2
3       B       2
6       A       1
6       A       0
2       B       3
2       C       3
5       A       3
5       B       1
```

and i want to add a new column `col_new` that counts the number of rows with the same elements in `col_1` and `col_2` but excluding that row itself and such that the element in `col_3` is 1 (regardless of the row element in `col_3` is actually `1` or not ). So the desired output would look like

````
col_1   col_2   col_3   col_new
6       A       1       1
2       A       1       0
5       B       1       1
3       C       1       0
5       C       2       0
3       B       2       0
6       A       1       1
6       A       0       1 (even though ```col_3``` value is 0)
2       B       3       0
2       C       3       0
5       A       3       0
5       B       1       1
````

What I have tried:

`df['col_new] = df[df['col_3' == 1]].groupby(['col_1', 'col_2'])['col_2'].transform('count').sub(1)`

which shows the correct result for those rows with `col_3` value `1` but `NaN` for rows with `col_3` value `0` (like row 8)

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Why not just say, in your filtering before the group-by, `df['col3'].isin([0, 1])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
df['col_new'] = (df.groupby(['col_1', 'col_2'])['col_3']
                   .transform('sum').sub(df['col_3'])
                 )
```

Or, to only consider 1s (not 2s):

```
s = df['col_3'].eq(1)
df['col_new'] = (df.assign(col_3=s)
                   .groupby(['col_1', 'col_2'])['col_3']
                   .transform('sum').sub(s)
                 )
```

Output:

```
    col_1 col_2  col_3  col_new
0       6     A      1        1
1       2     A      1        0
2       5     B      1        1
3       3     C      1        0
4       5     C      2        0
5       3     B      2        0
6       6     A      1        1
7       6     A      0        2  # both rows 1 and 6 match
8       2     B      3        0
9       2     C      3        0
10      5     A      3        0
11      5     B      1        1
``
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I do only want 1s and not the 2s so I believe the second one is closer to what I want. However, I want the value of ```col_new``` of row 7 to be 2 instead of 1 as both rows 1 and 6 satisfy the criteria and I want subtract one from it (even tho ```col_3```  != 1 for row 7 )

Comment: Why do you want to subtract 1? The logic is unclear.

Comment: Then just use `sub(1)` instead of `sub(s)` but you might have a negative value